# Magmi Import Simple Products Listing

Tags: magento

I sell Pet Supplies. My distributor provides me with a CVS file with all the nessacrty information for me to upload it to my website. I currently upload it as a simple product. But I would like it to be more user friendly. I am using Magento Community 1.7. I have tried messing with the configurable products but this is not possible for the upload I use.

Example: A Dog Cage comes in different sizes. Currently it shows as simple products and shows 5 different sizes. I would like it to show like all the bigger named stores. Basically show a dropdown with the different options. I tried creating a configurable product and associate the products I uploaded as a simple product but this method will not work. Any other ideas of what I can do? I want my customers to be able to click:
iCrate Double Door and have the options 18x24....24x30 etc. How do the other companies get them listed like this?

Comment: providedetails +1 for this question

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the right thing - configurable products will give you what you want to achieve.

You need to install the Magmi configurable product plugin. You also need to set your csv up so the simple products come first, then the configurable. To automatically associate the simple product with the parent configurable on import you need an extra column specifying the configurable attribute (see the Magmi docs) and the skus need set up so the simple skus are extended versions of the configurable's sku. Again, the Magmi wiki on configurables will explain more.

Answer (score 0):

You could also amend your grouped products to do similar and provide the list as a dropdown
check out this thread 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/208482/#t297046

Comment: Worked great thank you! I didn't even know this was an option for Magento!